# PyQt5) When I try to open Second window, it is closed without any error messages

Tags: pyqt5, qmainwindow

I'm trying to open second window on main window.

I made 2 classes for each windows, and run the code. when I click the button on main window, the main window is closed and second windows show. but after 1 seconds the second window is closed and the process ends.

Really I don't know why it does...

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)

        # Button
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.button.setText('Open Sub Window')
        self.button.setStyleSheet('font-size:40px')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.sub_show)

    def sub_show(self):
        self.hide()
        self.sub_window = SubWindow()
        self.sub_window.exec()
        self.show()

class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.button2.setText('Back to Main window')
        self.button2.setStyleSheet('font-size:40px')

        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.home)
        self.show()


    def home(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please avoid thanks or "help me" to questions, they are unnecessary. Also, always try to run your program on a terminal or prompt to see any possible debug and traceback that the IDE might not show.

Comment: @musicamante Ok, I'll keep it mind :D Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `show` a few to many times. Also `QWidget` doesn't have an `exec` method.  You will also want the first window to reappear when you close the second I assume.

I made some changes in the example below. Give it a try:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.button.setText('Open Sub Window')
        self.button.setStyleSheet('font-size:40px')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.sub_show)

    def sub_show(self):
        self.hide()
        self.sub_window = SubWindow()
        # connect signal to show again when button2 is pressed
        self.sub_window.button2.clicked.connect(self.show)
        self.sub_window.show()

class SubWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.button2.setText('Back to Main window')
        self.button2.setStyleSheet('font-size:40px')
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Wow... You saved my life. It perfectly works what I intended!! I gonna check what you pointed. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @khm please remember to mark post as answered

Comment: Actually, this is the first time that I post my question... so I'm not sure that I've done what you said... I accepted your answer. Is it right or do I have to something else...?

Comment: @khm  you did good :}